# why does apply() produce a list sometimes, and a vector others?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this piece of code:

```
p.data=samp_data[,c('t_het_f','t_ane_f','t_loh_f')]
str(p.data)
head(p.data)
colnames(p.data)
head(apply(p.data,1,which.max))
```

which for one set of data produces this result:

```
'data.frame':   449 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ t_het_f: num  0.663 0.688 0.746 0.429 0.484 ...
 $ t_ane_f: num  0.291 0.3 0.247 0.398 0.261 ...
 $ t_loh_f: num  0.04601 0.01236 0.00657 0.17376 0.2546 ...
    t_het_f   t_ane_f     t_loh_f
1 0.6629108 0.2910798 0.046009390
...
6 0.7019118 0.2589706 0.039117647
[1] "t_het_f" "t_ane_f" "t_loh_f"
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

But for another set of data produces:

```
'data.frame':   587 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ t_het_f: num  0.505 0.566 0.205 0.367 0.59 ...
 $ t_ane_f: num  0.491 0.182 0.745 0.42 0.251 ...
 $ t_loh_f: num  0.00427 0.25193 0.05003 0.21227 0.15891 ...
    t_het_f   t_ane_f     t_loh_f
1 0.5048134 0.4909143 0.004272287
...
6 0.8159115 0.1829711 0.001117381
[1] "t_het_f" "t_ane_f" "t_loh_f"
[[1]]
t_het_f 
      1 

[[2]]
t_het_f 
      1
```

Why would what looks to me like the same data structure (p.data) produce a vector in one case, and a list in another?

Comment: According to `?apply` `Returns a vector or array or list of values obtained by applying a function to margins of an array or matrix.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the same function (which.max) was applied in both cases, it was not obvious that it might be returning different length values for the two datasets.  The difference was being caused by the presence of 'NA' in the second dataset, but not in the first.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` `Value` in `apply` depends on the `length` of the output as mentioned in `?apply`

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1. If n equals 1, apply returns a vector if MARGIN has length 1 and an array of dimension dim(X)[MARGIN] otherwise. If n is 0, the result has length 0 but not necessarily the ‘correct’ dimension.

> If the calls to FUN return vectors of different lengths, apply returns a list of length prod(dim(X)[MARGIN]) with dim set to MARGIN if this has length greater than one.